# Can I convert ArrayList<HashMap> type to List<Map> in Java?

Tags: java

Can I convert `ArrayList<HashMap>` type to `List<Map>` in Java?
Otherwise, what is the official or recommended workaround?

I have two interfaces with two different but similar types - `ArrayList<HashMap>` and `List<Map>`, and I need to pass data from one interface to another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nizil no. If it worked, you would be able to add a TreeMap to a List<HashMap>. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Please read the concepts of Interface and Implementation in java.
Also the concept to "Design for Interface"
List and Map are Interface
Where as ArrayList and HashMap are particular implementations.
So you should have no problem with casting them. (Depending on actual data in instance of Object with List<Map>)

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, I forgot this one :) (I really need to stop my pythonic stuff and redo some Java :P)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be more specific in what you are asking. If you have a method with the signature

```
method1(List<Map> maps)
```

then you are not allowed to pass in a `List<HashMap>` (which includes `ArrayList<HashMap>`). If `method1` only reads from the list (i.e., uses the list as a *producer*, then the proper signature should be

```
method1(List<? extends Map> maps)
```

Also note that here `Map` is used as a raw type, which is also inappropriate. You should better use

```
method1(List<? extends Map<?,?> maps)
```

Comment: PECS - producer extends, consumer super

Answer (score 5):

I would change the interface that accepts/returns an `ArrayList<HashMap>` to accept/return a `List<Map>` instead. It is a better practice to use interface types.